# jquery ajax is not returning back to success function from MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm hitting a method in controller from `jquery ajax`. I have an `html` page outside the application from where I'm calling this method.

Below is the `ajax` code written on `html` page.

```
function SignIn() {
        var d = JSON.stringify({
            Email: $('#email').val(),
            Password: $('#password').val()
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:58954/Account/SignIn",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: d,
            success: function (e) {
                alert('success');

            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the code written in `controller's` method. I'm returning `Json object` from here.

```
[AjaxOnly(), HttpPost(), AllowAnonymous()]
    public ActionResult SignIn(AuthenticationModel model)
    {

     // here code written for authentication 

      dynamic jsonData = new {
            Message = errorMessage,
            HasError = HasError,
            RedirectUrl = redirectUrl
        };

        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

When ajax code run then it first goes to error function and shows me following details in alert.

[image]

After this it hits the method in `controller` and `code` runs perfectly as it should and after that it doesn't return back to ajax call's success function.

It shows the `Json object` on page as below:

[image]

Comment: have you tried looking at the actual HTTP request and the web server's response with Fiddler? could be a CORS issue, since you're calling it from an external page.

Comment: What is triggering your `SignIn()` function? I assume its a link or submit button and you have not cancelled the default event so you making a redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it is a submit button. Can you please tell me what it requires more to do?

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke , I believve you have the textboxes inside a form and on submit button click you are doing this ajax call which throws error, After this the actual form is also submitted. Option 1) Remove the form Tag completely as you are dealing with ajax here... Option 2) Use e.preventDefault(); to prevent your form submit event

Comment: try this    url: '@Url.Action("SignIn", "Account")', and check

Comment: @Reddy you are right. I have removed the form tag. Now it's showing me error on ajax call but not hitting the method.

Comment: You can start by using Unobtrusive Javascript and not polluting your markup with behavior. Change the submit button to `<button type="button" id="signin">Sign in</button>` and then the script will be `$('#signin').click(function() { ...... });`

Comment: And never hard code your urls like that. Always use `'@Url.Action()'`

Comment: He is sending JSON, And he cannot use `'@Url.Action()'` because he mentions its plain HTML site and Not MVC, he hits s MVC project running locally from the HTML site..

Comment: @CodeRider I think when you hit the MVC app from our HTML site the debugger is not enabled (just a wild guess). SO what you can do is take the data that is send via ajax and do the same thing in the MVC app too then you can debug and find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I have doubt in the way you are passing the data.

Try to pass the data without doing **stringify** and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. check if signin method is in document.ready function
2. if synchronous call is needed then you can use 'async': false
3. controller signin method expects AuthenticationModel as input parameter hence check ajax method returns the expected object, else try as string parameters in controller
4. as per the above controller code it always return jsondata which always returns error object in it.